# Realtime Textarea Character Count in Titanium App (iOS)

Tags: javascript, ios, uitextfield, titanium, appcelerator

I want to have a counter on my textfield that starts at 140 and subtracts the number of characters in the text area.

Here is my event listener:

```
contentArea.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    if(e.value.length >= 200) {
        contentArea.value = e.value.substring(0, 200);
    } else {
        countLabel.text = 140 - e.value.length;
    }
});
```

Basically, the user is allowed to submit if they have 140 or fewer characters. I don't want to just block it once they hit the limit, so I let them go a decent amount over. But I want to to update this count label with an accurate representation of their count.

**The problem is checking the count on every change automatically accepts any autocorrect suggestion and causes for a really bad UX.**

Is there any way around this?

Comment: You could turn off autocorrect.

Comment: @JosiahHester That's not a viable solution to this problem any more than removing the count is.

Comment: You are talking about the built in auto correct right? Or did you roll your own. Also, this functionality is baked into the [TextArea control](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TextArea-property-maxLength).

Comment: @JosiahHester Yes, I am talking about the built in autocorrect, which I still want to use. I know you can set a max length but that just stops the user from typing more characters at a certain point, it doesn't let them know how many they have left.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a messy way to do things but you could try adding a looping timer when the textArea focus() event fires, that keeps checking the length and updating the display. Then on the blur() event remove the timer.